# Background image size, Android

Tags: css, image

We have a problem with 2 projects already:

A big background image (to fill a big screen of a desktop PC) is displayed very small in the upper left corner of the smartphone display.

This is one of the used codes:

```
background: #7F7F7F url("../images/hg4.jpg") repeat left top scroll;
```

Perhaps there is a simple solution for all devices, or a detection and 2 versions are necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but you can try 
`background-size: cover;`
`background-position: center center;`
`background-attachement: fixed;`